# How to check empty collection for map.get(1) Java

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm beginner in Java. My Map variable returns an empty collection. How to check it.

```
    import java.util.Map;

    Map<Integer, Object> result = DataAccessLayer.selectQuery_pstmt(getWidgetById, paramArray2,false,"default");

    System.out.println("\n Result: "+result.get(1));

    It shows "[]" empty array

    // following condition doesn't work for it.

    if(result.get(1) != null){
       // condition
    }
```

Comment: The `Object` is not null - it is an empty array (it seems) - you need to cast the `Object` into its type and then gets its size or length (i.e. `((String[])result.get(1)).size() != 0)` if it is an array of `String` or `Array` if its a collection, etc.

Comment: `"[]"` represents an empty `Collection`, not an *Array*.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle: okay. Thanks. Corrected question.

Comment: You should use some conditions like that: `if(result != null) {
 if(result.get(1) != null) {
  if(result.get(1).size() > 0) {
   
  } 
 } 
}`

Comment: Significant nit:  why are your map values `Object`?  This makes casting/checking them for emptiness *incredibly* risky since you can't determine without casting if they're an `Iterable` or an array.

Answer (score 1):

1. Cast `result.get(1)` to Collection.

   `Collection res = (Collection) result.get(1);`
2. Then use `Collection#isEmpty()` to check if the return value is empty.

   `if(res !=null && !res.isEmpty()){}`

Answer (score 0):

Solved it myself.

```
List result1 = (ArrayList<Integer>) result.get(1);
System.out.println("-----"+result1.size());
```

Thanks for guidance.

Comment: calling `#size()` just to check for emptiness can be unnecessary overhead.Use `#isEmpty()` instead.

Comment: `List<Integer>` even if you were to do such a poor casting.